# yii2 inserting a value, when 'other' option is choosen, in dropdown list

Tags: yii2

I have a dropdown list in my form, and I would like to enable the user to an option of 'other', which would enable him to insert a value in to a text box, instead of a value from the dropdownlist.
Is that possible?

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'institution')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(Institution::find()->all(), 'iId', 'name'),    ['class'=>'form-control inline-block']); ?>
```

The same thing I would like to do with a radioList.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'selfDescription')->radioList(array('good'=>'good','very good'=>'very good','best'=>'best')); ?>
```

thanks.

Comment: Yes possible. Create a textbox and hide it. When use selects other in dropdown show that textbox using jQuery.

Comment: Consider using some enhanced listbox widgets like Selectize or Select2. They might already do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

First. Add "other" option to dropDownList. And handle it in your frontend with JS

```php
$form
    ->field($model, 'institution')
    ->dropDownList(
        ArrayHelper::map(Institution::find()->all(),
            'iId',
            'name'
        ) + ['other' => 'Other'],
        [
            'class'=>'form-control inline-block',
            // next code disables text field when any but "other" option is selected
            // works for jQuery 1.6+
            'onchange' => new JsExpression('
                $("#textFieldSelector").prop("disabled", $(this).find("option:selected").val() != "other");'),
        ]
    );
```

Then you need to set properly your validators. Just add

```php
['textField', 'required', 'when' => function($model) {
    return $model->institution === 'other';
}]
```